# Is it possible two hostnames share the same IP address?

Tags: url, ip, hostname

I'm confused whether is it possible that two hostnames share the same IP addresses? And why? 
What about if one hostname represent more than one IP address, is it possible too? And why?

*detailed explanation is really appreciated :)*

Comment: yes both are possible
see this for more detail explanations
http://serverfault.com/questions/517501/is-it-possible-for-two-hostnames-share-the-same-ip-address/517504?noredirect=1#517504

Answer (score 1):

I know of Apache Virtual Host, which allows webservers with different hostnames (domainnames), to be hosted on the same IP address.
The webserver sends the domainname we wants while connecting, and webserver returns the right set of pages.

Heres something more specific if you want to further look into it https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html